# Get List<String> of only one length when I split String with character array

Tags: c#, list, split, datacontractserializer

I use this property to help users filter results, by specifying what shouldn't appear. They can separate their terms with all the characters in `INCLUDE_INTERPRET_SEPARATORS`. The String is saved to an XML file at startup and close.

However, the List always end up with only 1 index. I wondered for some time whether it had to do with loading the values through XML deserialization, but breakpoints confirmed that the application uses the setters on startup.

After the update, I've confirmed that the splitting will work in a different environment. I still don't know why this code didn't work originally.

`_Exclude` and `Exclude` below, are different types on purpose.

```
private readonly char[] INCLUDE_INTERPRET_SEPARATORS = {';', '|', '+'};
private const string INCLUDE_SEPARATOR = ";";

private List<string> _Exclude = new List<string>();
[DataMember()]
public string Exclude
{
    get
    {
        return String.Join(INCLUDE_SEPARATOR, _Exclude);
    }
    set
    {
        string input = Utils.RemoveDiacritics(value);
        _Exclude = new List<string>(input.Split(INCLUDE_INTERPRET_SEPARATORS, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
        onPropertyChanged("Exclude");
    }
}
```

**Example**

In my XML file I have (amongst other things)

```
 <Episode>9</Episode>
 <Exclude>WEB-DL;1080i;MPEG</Exclude>
 <FilterEpisode>true</FilterEpisode>
```

Breakpoints show that `Exclude` is set to

```
Index  Value                 Type
[0]    "WEB-DL;1080i;MPEG"   String
```

Am I missing something obvious about this?

**Update**

I made a [test on dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hkwbto) and found that the code works in a simplified environment, without DataContractSerializer.

Similarly, when I add an extra property, it works:

```
    private readonly char[] INCLUDE_INTERPRET_SEPARATORS = {';', '|', '+'};
private const string INCLUDE_SEPARATOR = ";";

[IgnoreDataMember()]
public List<string> ExcludeList 
{ 
    get
    {
        return new List<string>(Exclude.Split(INCLUDE_INTERPRET_SEPARATORS, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
    }
}

private string _Exclude = "";
[DataMember()]
public string Exclude
{
    get
    {
        return _Exclude;
    }
    set
    {
        _Exclude = Utils.RemoveDiacritics(value);

        foreach (string x in ExcludeList)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(x);
        }

        onPropertyChanged("Exclude");
    }
}
```

**Update 2**

I figured out what the problem is. `INCLUDE_INTERPRET_SEPARATORS` is empty when the class object is loaded from XML deserialization. The string doesn't get split. By making fields like these static, they will still be initialized on startup.

Comment: Your list `"_Exclude"`  should have multiple values in it, but you have a `string` **"Exclude"** which is based on joined values from the List, that will have a single value. It appears you are not using the right names "Exclude" and "_Exclude" are confusing, considering "_Exclude" is not really a backing field with the same type.

Comment: I will add it to the post Habib so there's no more confusion. `input` is just a temporary String I use after I've removed diactritics from the user input.

Comment: Does any other code do anything with `_Exclude`?

Comment: The only other mention is in a method using `List<string> exclude = IgnoreCaps ? _Exclude.ConvertAll(s => s.ToLower()) : _Exclude;`.

Comment: @juharr I modified my answer, but I believe he is attempting to populate a Global List of data from each node.  So as it iterates each individual node it will add the value to a `List`.  Not entirely sure because the question is quite vague on intent.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are missing something.  When you set your breakpoint, check the value of _Exclude, not Exclude.

Comment: I have double checked it. It's a List with Count == 1

Comment: what do you get if you set Exclude to WEB-DL+1080i|MPEG

Comment: I got the same result. The whole string in index 0.

Comment: but what do you get in index 0?

Comment: The whole string `value` in the first index

Comment: Third times a charm, hopefully.  What is the literal string value you get in index 0?

Comment: Sorry. If I set Exclude to `WEB-DL+1080i|MPEG`, then _Exclude[0] = `WEB-DL+1080i|MPEG`

Comment: Where are you setting your breakpoint?  Did you try putting it in the setter and stepping through the set process

Comment: I put the breakpoint before `OnPropertyChanged`. I have both printed out and checked the values of `_Exclude`. I've updated the question. I found a solution. I suspect the reason for it failing had to do with deserialization.